# Is it possible to host a PHP web application under my own domain, but rewrite the url to another domainname?

Tags: php, apache, url, dns, url-rewriting

I'm currently building a simple web application in PHP that other company's can use as one of their services. I want to host the application myself and not install it on one of their servers, but i do want the accessibility that that would offer. *Example*:

www.mywebapp.com is where i would host the web application.
www.company.com would be the domain name of the client.

**webapp.company.com** should redirect to **www.mywebapp.com/?c=company**. Upon navigation, **webapp.company.com/view.php?v=test** would also be redirected to **www.mywebapp.com/view.php?c=company&v=test** and so on upon further using the web app.

Can someone explain how i can achieve this and if this is the best option considering my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I recommend that you switch to implementing an API.**  That's how this problem is solved by many corporations.  They simply have an API key that will let your server know what client they are and therefore what to serve them.

**Resources on API's:**

- Google Tech Talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw [1:00:19 long]
- http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/01/06/from-the-trenches-web-api-design-best-practices/
- Directory of some existing API's: http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory

---

I think your idea IS possible if both servers are set up correctly, but doesn't it feel wrong to you?

Comment: It certainly did feel wrong, but i hadnt given an API a second thought. I'll definitely look into it more. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have an 'a' record for both domains pointing to the same server

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all#section-rewrite_sub-domains